# Wcf with framework 4.0

Tags: wcf, iis, frameworks

After installing Wcf on server(runs: ws 2008, x64, framework 4.0, IIS 7.5) i got this error:

```
The current identity (IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0) does not have write access to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.
```

I tried to build in x64 but same error.

I saw this post but doesnt really understand what todo.
http://windowsclient.net/blogs/sameh/archive/2010/06/13/wcf-4-0-issues-with-iis-7-0-on-x86-and-x64-bit-machines.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

[Does user write permissions to the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder pose any security problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096400/does-user-write-permissions-to-the-temporary-asp-net-files-folder-pose-any-securi)

The link you posted does not seem to be related to the issue you are having. You need to set the permissions on the folder, not reset the installation.